# Using @Singleton without @Provides in Dagger

Tags: dependency-injection, dagger

A small example of a module that injects a class `Foo`:

```
@Module(complete = false, injects = { Foo.class })
class MyModule { }

class Foo {
    @Inject
    Foo(Bar bar, Baz baz) { }
}
```

(assuming that `Bar` and `Baz` are provided by a different module)

I now want `Foo` to be a singleton.

I could add a `@Provides` method and annotate it with `@Singleton` ...

```
@Module(complete = false, injects = { Foo.class })
class MyModule {
    @Provides @Singleton Foo provideFoo(Bar bar, Baz baz) {
        return new Foo(bar, baz);
    }
}
```

... but having to write that constructor invocation myself kind of defeats the purpose of using an injection framework. Is there a shorter way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

You can add `@Singleton` to `class Foo {}` and when Foo is instantiated via implicit binding, it will be bound as @Singleton. eg:

```
@Module(complete = false, injects = { Foo.class })
class MyModule { }

@Singleton
class Foo {
  @Inject
  Foo(Bar bar, Baz baz) { }
}
```

---

## Scope

The caveat here is that if it is implicitly bound, but not referred to, in a root graph, extension graphs (.plus() generated graphs) may inadvertently instantiate it, so you need to either declare it as an entry-point (injects=) (which you did in your example), or it needs to be consumed by something reachable by an entry-point.

If you're not using .plus() for scoping/lifetime management, then this last point is not that important.  But @Singleton means one-per-graph, and graphs' implicit bindings are only realized on-demand.  An upcoming feature to allow custom scope annotations to be used will catch these errors.

Comment: Ah, I misread the documentation - I latched onto the phrase "serves as documentation", so I took that to mean that @Singleton on a class doesn't have any practical effect, neglecting to read the first sentence in that section.

Comment: Are there any changes here for Dagger2?